# How can I change my game resolution with changing camera size?

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Hello Everyone I am new In unity and I don't know more about Unity Camera.
I am Working On one Game right now And In this game I set One background Image Which is look pretty in  Free Aspect Ratio.
But at run Time When I change the resolution of game the size of the background is changed.and I set 3D Texts on It and Their Position has also changed.
I have seen Couple of Tutorials On It but That Does't feet to my requirement, so can any One help me or Explain me that How It works Or Give me any Sample code.

Comment: There's no need to introduce or thank or greet or sign or beg forgiveness or any such writing. Just include what's important for the question. You also have your website listed in the profile, that has to suffice. Links should only be added if they are important for the question or answer.

Comment: I need answer for my question bro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Background image directly. Just add GUITexture to your scene Then Put your Background Image to GUITexture and see this [LINK](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/150736/script-gui-units.html) add the code. [CHECK](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1PRFC_enIN590IN591&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=constant%20background%20images%20for%20different%20ratio%20in%20unity3d)

Comment: Thanks a lot Rasa.

Now it works on my code.


Thanks.

regards,
[Dharmesh](http://www.variyasoftsolutions.com/unity3d.html)